# How to perform textbox search with matching dropdown options using only JavaScript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am working on a Web development project. I need to take some input like bank name in a textbox. After user starts typing 3 letters, I need to show all the matching options below (Not clear how to show). In the below options user can click any one options and the clicked text should be pasted in the same text box. All should be in html, css, js or ajax.

So far I created a text box and an `ul` list with no `li` in it and this ordered list is hidden by default. I created onkeyup event for the textbox. As the user starts typing bank names, if the text length is `>=3` (Since banks keyword is minimum 3), I am filling that `ul` with the matching data using ajax and unhide it.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a Bank" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" hidden onclick="selectBank()">
```

And the script is:

```
<script>
  function myFunction(){

    var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
    var len = inp.value.length;

    if(len>=3){
      LoadBanks();
      $("#myUL").show();
    }else{
      $('#myUL').empty();
      $("#myUL").hide();
    }
  }

  function LoadBanks(){
    // for now the key is static. i will be updating it with the user input
    var payload = {"key":"SBI"}
    
    $.ajax({
      url:"url",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function (data){
        jsonObj = data.bankList;
        var list = document.getElementById("myUL");

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
          var bank = jsonObj[i].banka;
          var bankl = jsonObj[i].bankl;
          var t = document.createElement('li');
          t.innerHTML= bank+"-"+bankl;
          list.appendChild(t);
        }
      },

      error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

The data is loaded sucessfully. But I don't know how to take text of which item is selected from that li's in onclick event.

Comment: What have you tried so far? WHat is your code? Where does the data come from etc.? There isn't enough information in the question to answer this in a helpful way.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like jQuerys autocomplete function? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Edited more clearly. Somehow i managed to load data. But i don't know how to fetch the clicked element from the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can write click event on `li` then inside that use `$(this).text()` this will give you text from li which is clicked then add that in your input-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just demo datas ..
var data = {
  "bankList": [{
    "banka": "cdc",
    "bankl": "cdcde"
  }, {
    "banka": "cdc1",
    "bankl": "cdcde1"
  }, {
    "banka": "cdc2",
    "bankl": "cdcde2"
  }]

}


function myFunction() {

  var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
  var len = inp.value.length;

  if (len >= 3) {
    LoadBanks();
    $("#myUL").show();
  } else {
    $('#myUL').empty();
    $("#myUL").hide();
  }
}

function LoadBanks() {
  /*$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {*/
  jsonObj = data.bankList;
  var list = document.getElementById("myUL");
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    var bank = jsonObj[i].banka;
    var bankl = jsonObj[i].bankl;
    var t = document.createElement('li');
    t.innerHTML = bank + "-" + bankl;
    list.appendChild(t);
  }
  /*},

   error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });*/
}
//on click of li..
$("#myUL").on("click", "li", function() {
  //get text add inside inputs
  $("#selected").val($(this).text().split("-")[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a Bank" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" hidden></ul>
<input type="text" id="selected">
```